# Keep bootstrap collapse from opening when I render another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view I have various partials that when rendered have a bootstrap collapse with some content.

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= render 'contact_phones', f: f %>
    <%= render 'contact_emails', f: f %>
    <%= render 'contact_websites', f: f %>
    <%= render 'contact_addresses', f: f %>
    <%= render 'contact_gym_contacts', f: f %>
    <%= render 'contact_notes', f: f %>
 </div>
```

Each partial has content similar to this

```
<% if params[:phones].blank? %>
    <%= link_to "#{url_for(params.merge({phones: 1, anchor: 'phones_collapse'}))}" do %>
      <%= t('activerecord.models.phone.other').capitalize %>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
   <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#phones_collapse" aria-controls="phones_collapse"><%= t('activerecord.models.phone.other').capitalize %>
     <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
   </a>
   <div id="phones_collapse" class="collapse in" >
     <%= render(layout: 'resourceable/application/resourceable_association', locals: {f: f, resource_association: Contact.resource_association(:phones)}) do |builder| %>
       <% if builder.object.persisted? %><p><%= link_to I18n.t('call_with_my_extension'), call_phone_url(builder.object), :remote => 'true' %></p><% end %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

After rendering one partial, and then collapsing it, if I render another partial (clicking on the link), the first one opens again. After having been rendered the first time, they stay closed, if I open another one. The problem is only when I render the first time, anything else that had been opened opens again even if it had been collapsed.

Rendering the partials adds to the URL, and I suppose the URL is sent each time I click a link, opening previous collapses, something like this

`contacts=1&phones=1&websites=1#gym_contacts_collapse`

If I can find a way to check if the partial has been rendered yet (in a test I can check for content, but how to get that in the view?). Then I can try manipulating the collapse and collapse in classes.  I've tried manipulating the URL with window.location and window.location.replace with no luck.

```
My idea:
When I click on the link:
  if this partial hasn't been rendered yet
    if other collapsible are closed, 
     they stay closed.
    if open, 
      they stay open.
```

Sorry if the question is a repeat or convoluted, thanks in advance.  Maybe this is more simple than I'm making it